# $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}|f(x)|^{3/2}dx\leq (\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}|\nabla f(x)|dx)^{3/2}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality, lebesgue-integral

This is an old prelim problem that I'm doing for practice.

So suppose that we have $f,\nabla f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$.  Show that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}|f(x)|^{3/2}dx\leq (\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}|\nabla f(x)|dx)^{3/2}$$

I have absolutely no idea how to start this problem. I thought of using integration by parts or something akin to that, but didn't get anywhere.

**EDIT:** Note sure if it helps or not, but the inequality can be rephrased as.

$$ ||f||_{L^{3/2}}\leq ||\nabla f||_{L^1}$$

This seems like an inequality involving Sobolev spaces or the like.

Comment: Maybe this will be useful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Gagliardo–Nirenberg–Sobolev inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Gagliardo.E2.80.93Nirenberg.E2.80.93Sobolev_inequality) for $p=1$ and $n=3$.

Comment: Thanks! Also the wiki says it says for functions of compact support, but I'm guessing we just use a density argument for the general case.

Comment: Yes, you can use density for the general case.